# How I can connect two fragments and write listeners in adapter

Tags: java, android, fragment, listener, adapter

I have 2 fragments. When I click like in one fragment, in the second fragment must appear news, which I liked.

Here is my favourite fragment I have a method Add()

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FavouriteListAdapter adapter;
private List<News> newsList;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite, container, 
 false);
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_favourite);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    newsList= new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new FavouriteListAdapter(newsList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}


public void addNews(News news) {
    newsList.add(news);
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(newsList.size() - 1);
}
```

In Home Fragment I use interface listener and add

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_home);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    listener = new NewsListAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void  likeClick(int position, News item) {
            add.respond(item);
            newsListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        }
    };
    add = new NewsListAdapter.Add() {
        @Override
        public void respond(News news) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).respond(news);
        }
    };
    newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(newsGenerator(), listener, add);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Adapter for Home

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsListAdapter.NewsViewHolder holder, final int position) 
{
    final News news = mainList.get(position);
    holder.theme.setText(news.getTheme());


    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener!=null){
                listener.likeClick(position,news);
            }
        }
    });

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mainList.size();
}

public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView theme;
    private ImageButton like;

    public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        theme = itemView.findViewById(R.id.theme);
        like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
    }
}
interface ItemClickListener {
    void likeClick(int position, News item);
}
public interface Add{
    void respond(News news);
}
```

Adaper for favourites. Adapter favourites contains News and we call method add here in MainActivity

```
@NonNull
@Override
public FavouriteListAdapter.FavouriteNewsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, 
 int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news, null,false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    view.setLayoutParams(params);

    return new FavouriteNewsHolder(view);
  }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FavouriteListAdapter.FavouriteNewsHolder holder, int 
position) {
    final News news = newsList.get(position);
    holder.theme.setText(news.getTheme());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsList.size();
}

public class FavouriteNewsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView theme;
    ImageButton like;
    public FavouriteNewsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        theme = itemView.findViewById(R.id.theme);
        like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
    }
}
```

in Activity I overwrite my method. When I execute my programm and click button click the program stopping

```
@Override
public void respond(News news) {
       FavouriteFragment f = (FavouriteFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    f.addNews(news);
}
```

In logcat:
2020-03-24 21:55:12.367 13933-13933/com.example.newsfragment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newsfragment, PID: 13933
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.newsfragment.HomeFragment cannot be cast to com.example.newsfragment.FavouriteFragment
        at com.example.newsfragment.MainActivity.respond(MainActivity.java:50)
        at com.example.newsfragment.HomeFragment$2.respond(HomeFragment.java:51)
        at com.example.newsfragment.HomeFragment$1.likeClick(HomeFragment.java:43)
        at com.example.newsfragment.NewsListAdapter$1.onClick(NewsListAdapter.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

The 50 line in MainActivity

```
   public void respond(News news) {
   FavouriteFragment f = (FavouriteFragment) 
   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
   f.addNews(news);
   }
```

Comment: What, exaclty, is your problem? Is it that nothing appears in the second fragment when you click on ___like___ in the first fragment?

Comment: Also just post the code that reflects your problem,. People will pass on questions that are too hard to figure out

Comment: @Abra The app is breaking down, when I click like -

Comment: _The app is breaking down_ Do you mean it crashes? Do you get an error? What appears in `logcat` ?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and post the `logcat` output and also indicate which is line 50 in file `MainActivity.java`

Comment: @Abra I changed question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the eventBus for this type of communication with a fragment. Using https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus this lib I have implemented the same things(When like a post in homeFragment at that time I want to like that post in multiple fragments)

Register and unregister EventBus

```
 @Override public void onStart() {
 super.onStart();
 EventBus.getDefault().register(this);  }

 @Override public void onStop() {
 super.onStop();
 EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);  }
```

Post events:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Comment: Maybe you can post some sample code demonstrating how to use `eventBus` for communicating with a fragment?